# Foreign key constraint failure in Django's django_admin_log table IntegrityError 1452 AbstractBaseUser

Tags: python, mysql, django, authentication, model

I'm encountering an error related to a foreign key constraint while working on a Django project. When attempting to add or update records in the django_admin_log table, the following error occurs:

here is my model.py:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractBaseUser, BaseUserManager, PermissionsMixin, Permission,Group
from django.db import models
from django.core.validators import EmailValidator
from django.core.exceptions import ValidationError
import re
from phonenumber_field.modelfields import PhoneNumberField
from apps.location.models import City
from django.utils import timezone

class CustomUserManager(BaseUserManager):
    def create_user(self, email, password=None, **extra_fields):
        if not email:
            raise ValueError('The Email field must be set')
        email = self.normalize_email(email)
        user = self.model(email=email, **extra_fields)
        user.set_password(password)
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user

    def create_superuser(self, email, password=None, **extra_fields):
        extra_fields.setdefault('is_staff', True)
        extra_fields.setdefault('is_superuser', True)

        if extra_fields.get('is_staff') is not True:
            raise ValueError('Superuser must have is_staff=True.')
        if extra_fields.get('is_superuser') is not True:
            raise ValueError('Superuser must have is_superuser=True.')

        return self.create_user(email, password, **extra_fields)

class UserType(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30, unique=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


def validate_password_strength(value):
    if not re.match(r'^(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[!@#$%^&*()_+{}|:;<>,.?/~]).{8,}$', value):
        raise ValidationError("Password must meet the specified requirements.")


class CustomUser(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    email = models.EmailField(unique=True, validators=[EmailValidator(message="Enter a valid email address.")])
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    city = models.ForeignKey(City, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=50)# Add the address field
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    is_staff = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    user_type = models.ForeignKey(UserType, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)
    date_joined = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    last_login = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    profile_image = models.ImageField(upload_to='user_images/', blank=True, null=True)
    password = models.CharField(max_length=128, validators=[validate_password_strength])
    phone_number = PhoneNumberField(unique=True)
    date_joined = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now, editable=False)  # Use 'date_joined' for time of registration

# Additional field for password confirmation
    password_confirmation = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    groups = models.ManyToManyField(Group, blank=True, related_name='customuser_set')
    user_permissions = models.ManyToManyField(Permission, blank=True, related_name='customuser_set')
    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['first_name', 'last_name', 'address', 'phone_number','date_joined']
    objects = CustomUserManager()

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)

        if self.user_type and self.user_type.name == "Majstor":
            if not hasattr(self, 'majstor_profile'):
                MajstorProfile.objects.create(user=self)
            else:
                self.majstor_profile.save()
        else:
            if hasattr(self, 'majstor_profile'):
                self.majstor_profile.delete()

class MajstorProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(CustomUser, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='majstor_profile')
    bio = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    education = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)
    years_of_activity = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)
    services_role = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return f"Profile for {self.user.email} - {self.user.user_type.name}"

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Majstor Profile'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Majstor Profiles'

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if self.user.user_type.name == "Majstor":
            super(MajstorProfile, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
        else:
            # You can choose to not save the profile for other user types
            # or raise an exception or handle it in any other way as needed.
            pass
```

And I set it up in my settings.py:

```
AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'user.CustomUser'
```

After creating a new superuser and logging into my admin panel. It works fine, but after I want to add or change stuff in my db error is displayed:

```
(1452, 'Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`popravi_db`.`django_admin_log`, CONSTRAINT `django_admin_log_user_id_c564eba6_fk_auth_user_id` FOREIGN KEY (`user_id`) REFERENCES `auth_user` (`id`))')
```

I tried deleting migrations and db but still getting the same error.

Issue Overview:

1. The error message seems to indicate a problem with the user_id field in the django_admin_log table, referencing the auth_user table.
2. I have verified that the user_id values I'm trying to insert or update existing in the auth_user table.
3. I'm using Django and suspect that there might be an issue with the foreign key relationship or data integrity.